# How does the MD5 function work?

Tags: c, openssl

I'd like to implent a function for [SuperFastHash](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html) that is compatible so openssl's MD5 function.
MD5 is declared in md5.h as:

```
unsigned char *MD5(const unsigned char *d, size_t n, unsigned char *md);
```

But I can't find it's definition in the headers and the sourcecode.

So how does it work exactly? The function not the algorithm.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer that was given you, I'd like to point out that openssl implementation if md5 can be found in openssl tarball that is available from here http://www.openssl.org/source/

You are after crypto\md5\asm folder inside it.

Comment: Asambler is as crytic to me as a MD5 hash of unknown data actually. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321